# Eliminate weird gray box at bottom of web page

Tags: html, css

I'm not a web developer by any means, but I tried my best with a site my company launched. I wrote the code for https://nullptrsec.io, but for some weird reason, if the page is made scrollable, this gray box appears at the bottom of the initially rendered page. I have tried many things to eliminate it (various CSS) hacks. I know that you're supposed to list what you tried, but because I tried so much, I figured that would be pretty lengthy.

To replicate this issue, you can visit https://nullptrsec.io on a mobile device or use your browser to mimic portable dimensions (through dev tools). I'm trying to eliminate this gray box but cannot figure it out!

Comment: you have a bg color on your html element in `cover.css`. Remove it or change it to the same blue color.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked through your page and I see that the body isn't adjusting itself to your content, and the body is the component that has that certain blue color over the gray.

Adding the h-auto to you body should solve this:

> class="company bg h-auto"

Comment: This was the exact fix. Thank you so much!